# How to find out the longest allowed query string length for Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I found some scattered information about the max size of a query, where it varies from 20mb to more than 1gb.

I have a long query string that is to insert about 200k rows in a table. In debug output I see that the string is `39759604` characters long, which is roughly 38mb in size.

Executing this query leads to connection being terminated then database goes into recovery mode.

If I reduce the size of the query string by making less data in it, the query runs successfully.

I have 16Gb of RAM and seeing that 9 of it is used.

Here is the ouput of Postgres log:

```
2017-10-13 12:51:03.110 UTC [1] LOG:  server process (PID 93) was terminated by signal 9: Killed 
2017-10-13 12:51:03.110 UTC [1] DETAIL: Failed process was running: INSERT INTO stats(...) VALUES ... 
2017-10-13 12:51:03.115 UTC [1] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes 
2017-10-13 12:51:03.115 UTC [116] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process 
2017-10-13 12:51:03.115 UTC [116] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory. 
2017-10-13 12:51:03.115 UTC [116] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
```

How do I know what max query size can I use in my particular case?

Comment: would you consider refactoring the query?.. I mean it probably depends of kernel settings, but maybe you better change the approach?..

Comment: I tried to run each row insertion query as a single command and it takes quite much longer.

Comment: so you have `insert ... VALUES(),(),()...` which size to 38 MB?.. then generating csv and then `COPY` will be both much faster and safier I believe

Comment: Yes, it looks like this:
```INSERT INTO stats(country, crop, parameter, geo_entity_type, geo_entity_id, year, doy, value) VALUES ('US', 5, 'yield', 'state', 29, 2009, 285, 42.0),('US', 5, 'yield', 'state', 29, 2009, 285, 42.0), ...```

Comment: how do you generate the statement?..

Comment: It's generated as a string from an array of objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156667/discussion-between-vao-tsun-and-sergei-basharov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try another approach than trying to ajust the max length of statement. If you generate statement, you can generate csv (or possibly already have it). loading csv to the table is much faster then multiline `INSERT`.

In case you need some transformation before you load the data, you could `COPY FROM csv` to a temporary auxilary table and then `INSERT INTO orig SELECT transfor FROM temp`. Or even try some tools designed for such task, eg:
http://pgloader.io/howto/pgloader.1.html

> -l , --load-lisp-file : Specify a lisp to compile and load into the pgloader image before reading the commands, allowing to
>   define extra transformation function. Those functions should be
>   defined in the pgloader.transforms package. This option can appear
>   more than once in the command line.

**update**
also, answering the original post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/131425/30035

> So a query is limited to 1 gigabyte (2^30) in size, minus 1 byte for a
>   terminating null byte.

But I think you will hit other limits before the SQL length